# Java Array of Enum (classes)

Tags: java, arrays, enums

How feasible is to do something like this? Consider `Enum*` a `enum Enum* { /* ... */ }`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ?[] types = new ?[] { Enum1, Enum2, Enum3 };

  for(? type : types) {
    for(Enum elem : type.values() { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

My main requirement is basically a bunch of String constants, each one grouped in a different type. Would I be better set with a bidimensional String array (`String[][]`)? I'd like some more constrained values, rather than types[j] where `j==1` is `A`, and `j==2` is `B`.

I know I could play around with reflection, but I dare say it would turn out too complex and then, less readable.

Comment: Can't you just use `Map<String, Set<String>> typeToConstants` to hold your String constants?

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov Yes, I could. That'd be better than a `String[][]` but I was looking for something more statically-typed, to see if it's possible.

Comment: @Alxe - So, just to get this straight, your looking to have an array of enum types?

Comment: @Rudi Yes, of Enum _types_, not Enum _objects_.

Comment: @Alxe - Okay, I will put together a suggestion in the answer.Technically speaking it will hold enums, not types, but the effect will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this construction could solve your problem:

```
    enum SomeEnum {
        A("one", "two", "three"),
        B("hello", "there");

        public final String[] constants;

        SomeEnum(String... constants) {
            this.constants = constants;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simple and fancy, looks great, as I only need to iterate over it's values. Thanks!

Comment: An small suggestion is that, integrity-wise, `constants` should be encapsulated by a method, say `constants()`, which returns `Arrays.copyOf(constants, constants.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you could create an `Enum[][]` which would store a list of lists of enums. This would look something like this.

```
public class Test {

    enum Birds {BIG_BIRD, MEDIUM_BIRD, SMALL_BIRD};
    enum Dogs {BIG_DOG, MEDIUM_DOG, SMALL_DOG};
    enum Bugs {BIG_BUG, MEDIUM_BUG, SMALL_BUG};
    Enum[][] enums = {Birds.values(),Dogs.values(),Bugs.values()};

}
```

You could then run `enums` through a nested loop to get the values. Something like;

```
    for(Enum[] e : enums){ 
        for(Enum e2 : e){ 
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
```

Which would give you the output;

```
BIG_BIRD
MEDIUM_BIRD
SMALL_BIRD   
BIG_DOG
MEDIUM_DOG
SMALL_DOG
BIG_BUG
MEDIUM_BUG
SMALL_BUG
```

You could go even further and declare constants that represented the numerical value that stores the types. Such as;

```
public static final byte BIRDS = 0;
public static final byte DOGS = 1;
public static final byte BUGS = 2;
```

Then you could access the specific type from the array by going;

```
for(Enum e: enums[Test.BIRDS]) System.out.println((Birds)e);
```